# Alternatives to springs for recessed can light trims?

Tags: light-fixture, recessed-lighting

Does anyone know of **a good alternative** to the specialized springs normally used to secure the trim of a recessed light to the fixture? They look like this:

I am installing about 40 trims and for whatever reason we are missing most of the springs. It is possible to buy replacements in small quantities, but they end up being over $1 (US) per spring which seems ridiculous and does add up.

[image]

Photos of how the springs attach to the trim:

[image]

and from the trim to the inside of the lighting fixture ("can"):

[image]

I'm thinking along the lines of some kind of material such as: rubber bands , stretchy string, common springs, quick ties etc. which would serve as a long-lasting substitute.

(Aside from sufficient strength the key feature of these springs is that they allow the trim to be installed without visible fasteners. So I'm not looking for a "band aid" solution using screws, tape, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of recessed lighting. I've run into this a few times and have used common springs. You have to shape the ends to fit into the can. Rubber bands and elastic string won't stand up to the heat long term.

Instead, exact replacements are [available online](http://www.electricbargainstores.com/product-p/juno-g24.htm?msclkid=9bb2651d85b018811b91384) at $1.18 for two.

Since you're installing 40 trims and need two "springs" per trim, any retrofits will take a lot more time to install. It might be worth the price to buy the springs and do it right. Good luck.

Comment: I agree. ~$.70 each (after shipping) seems like a bargain for a sure and convenient solution. No way I'd wrestle with getting standard springs connected up in there to save $.25 each or whatever.

Comment: You are great at editing. I'm an engineer so I'm lousy at it.